# How to prevent both routes from being matched in react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

If the path is `/posts/new`, both components `PostsNew` and `PostsShow` below will be rendered, and the `:id` is matched, with `id` being the word `new` instead of a number:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <Router>
        <App>
          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
          <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew} />
          <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
        </App>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

In App.js:

```
  <div>
    <h1>An awesome App</h1>
      {this.props.children}
  </div>
```

How can `/posts/new` not get matched twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We call this "ambiguous routes" and there's an example on our site [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/ambiguous-matches).

The Switch component should solve this.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <Router>
        <App>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
            <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew} />
            <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
          </Switch>
        </App>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: yes, it works!  So we would also `import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";` as well

Comment: the page there described it as "[use `Switch` to] clear up any ambiguous matching"